# Keyboard drivers don't work

Tags: drivers, keyboard

My keyboard just stopped working all of a sudden one morning. I have a Corsair k55 keyboard. The media keys work: pause, play, stop, next, and volume up/down and mute. But nothing else. It works when plugged in to a different computer though. Here is what I have tried. I have Windows 10

- Deleting the 2 "HID Keyboard device" in device manager which both had yellow triangles, code 37, and searching for changes.
- Tried a different keyboard. Same stuff
- Tried deleting ghost versions off the hid keyboard device.
- Went into cmd and entered "sfc /scannow" and found corrupt files and sucsessfully repaired
- Tried to update drivers in device manager
- Tried switching USB port.
- Uninstalling "Corsair composite virtual input device" in device manager

What more can I try?

Comment: Windows has built in keyboard drivers and most keyboards do not have separate drivers. Try a Windows 10 Repair Install:    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: Installation media? https://imgur.com/a/pIYMQge

Comment: If you are already on V2004, choose the second choice and run in place. If you are earlier than V2004, you can still use the second choice and run in place. You can see if your computer will upgrade to V2004.  But the second choice, and then select Run to launch the repair works.

Comment: Just To be clear I clicked the download tool now and not update now on the link you sent, https://imgur.com/a/CU3Ftr6

Comment: You can use the second choice in your link. When you click on that. select Run (not download).  If you did download, you can run Setup in the location where you downloaded. That will also run the repair

Comment: Not sure where to click run instead of download as it asks which media to use, Usb flash driver or ISO file

Comment: When you download to a media, click Setup in the Media folder (your download). Also, any modern browser will prompt you to run (open) or Save. Look there.

Comment: I would do a repair before doing a fresh install. A fresh install is a lot more bother.

Comment: @SimonMagnusson Clean install **_not_** required - a Repair Install may be, _but not until the following has been completed and shown not to fix this simple peripheral driver issue_: **(1)** Download and install the keyboard drivers from Corsair; **(2)** Run the following _in the order listed_, as `SFC` should _never_ run prior to `DISM`: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` > `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` > Reboot > `SFC /ScanNow` > Reboot > Run Windows Update, which will install any missing WHQL drivers

Comment: @John While normal keyboards generally do not have OEM drivers, ones with specialized keys and features almost always do. I'm not understanding why you're recommending a Repair Install when the means to repair a Windows install have not been tried yet _(`DISM`'s `/StartComponentCleanup` then `/RestoreHealth`, followed by `SFC`'s `/ScanNow`, the three of which **must** be run in the order listed for correct functionality)_

Comment: I do not usually see keyboard problems. Repair Install is not an issue so no harm in trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think your windows installation is corrupted:

1. Boot to **Safe Mode** *(with necessary drives enabled)*

   1. Run an antivirus scan
   2. Determine if the keyboard works

      - *If it doesn't:* 
        Perform a Clean Install and check if issue resolves
      - *If it does:* 
         System files are okay because if damaged, Safe Mode wouldn't work either
2. Disable all unnecessary Startup programs, services, etc. via `msconfig`

   - Tick the box to hide Microsoft services before disabling all.